Paper/By Hand Ciphers
What is a good hand cipher that is nearly impossible to break by hand, but easily encryptable by hand (e.g. 2 seconds for each character after <120 second keystream generation), and would take a computer more than 5 minutes to crack? I haven't found anything in the middle section of pretty secure ciphers.
Of course, the attacker would know the algorithm used to encrypt.
And, as an aside, would there be a similar relatively secure way to asymmetrically agree on a key? (allowing for secure asymmetric communication in the absence of computers)

seconds, minutes, these are problematic units since they depend on the computer.
